# SQL Server Stored Procedure Email verification

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an ASP.net that requests client's information from stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 based on a client's email address until the `@` sign. Since the clients often change after 3 months in this small organization, but the email addresses remain the same.

E.g. a client with email address `obois_in4@cegepoutaouais.qc.ca` finishes his/her contract after 3-4 months and then that email address is assigned to someone else.

Now, here's my question: I want my stored procedure to find the client information, after he/she entered `obois_in4` and presses the `Search` button. The reason I don't want them to enter the whole email is because it's too long, and secondly they can make a mistake while typing, but typing such as `obois_in4` isn't a big deal.

I wrote a code that can search a client by name, but again, the clients always change after 3-4 months but the email address remains the same.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_find_client_information] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@client_email varchar (50) = null
AS Declare @numOfRows int BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @numOfRows = COUNT (*)
    From helpdesk_clients 
Where --change first name and 
    client_firstName = @client_email or client_lastName = @client_email;

begin
if (@numOfRows = 0)
    select @numOfRows;
else if (@numOfRows = 1)
select 
    client_id,
    client_firstName, 
    client_lastName, 
    client_work_email, 
    client_work_phone, 
    client_work_phone_ext, 
    client_office, 
    dept_nom,
    client_position 

from 
    helpdesk_clients join departments
    on 
    helpdesk_clients.dept_id = departments.dept_id 
    where client_firstName like '%'+@client_email+'%';
end
END
```

The email address always starts with `obois` followed by an underscore `_` then the name of the department information technology as `in` and then by a digit such as `4` in this case. e.g. `obois_in4@cegepoutaouais.qc.ca`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised nobody even bothered looking into this. The best solution is to use `Substring()` and `CharIndex()`

With `SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )` we can truncate the string starting from a position within the string until a specified position within a string. With `CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )`, we can find the the position of a character within a given string.

`substring (work_email, 1, CHARINDEX('@', work_email)-1) = @work_email` ensures that a parameter doesn't have to be like `shawn.smith@cegepoutaouais.qc.ca`, and it's a big hassle for a client to enter his full email like `shawn.smith@cegepoutaouais.qc.ca`, he will only be required to enter `shwan.smith`, the script will search for `shawn.smith` in `shawn.smith@cegepoutaouais.qc.ca` until the `@` sign.

e.g.

In the stored procedure, assuming the `@work_email` is parameter and it's value is 'shawn.smith'

```
select 
client_id,
client_firstName, 
client_lastName, 
client_work_email, 
client_work_phone, 
client_work_phone_ext, 
client_office, 
dept_nom,
client_position 
 from 
helpdesk_clients join departments
on 
helpdesk_clients.dept_id = departments.dept_id 
where  substring (work_email, 1, CHARINDEX('@', work_email)-1) = @work_email;
```

Will return the all the details mentioned in the `Select` statement.